# Regular expression pattern matching with required conditions

Tags: python, python-re

How can I write a regex pattern that matches the following pattern:

1. Starting with `0/2/a/Q`.
2. Must end with `S/d`.
3. Must contain at least two `0`s.
4. Only contain Alphanumeric characters and the only special character `$` (Dollar sign).

I have tried this out, but the two `0`s condition is not satisfied by my code:

```
import re


data = '''
    Hello everyone, good evening, I am kanchon and I am from RUET. Now I am writing my assignment for automata code and trying to solve out this problem.
    Some dummy content line is following:
    022jdshjgh$dgdg Quite$stupid this is enough
'''
date_pattern = re.compile(r'[02aQ][a-zA-Z0-9$]+[Sd]')
dates = date_pattern.findall(data)

print(dates)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give some example input and output?

Comment: sorry, edited.... but how can satisfy 'must contain at least two 0' with this code?

Comment: thanks Mr. Tomerikoo, I am new in stackoverflow.... but I cannot fix the solution with answer given below

Comment: To match within other text, you would use `(?:^|\s)(?=.*0.*0)[02aQ][a-zA-Z0-9$]+[Sd](?=\s|$)`

Comment: thanks finally it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your description and add a lookahead:

```
^(?=.*?0.*0)[02aQ][a-zA-Z0-9$]+[Sd]$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rz4JqD/3/)

That works for a single string on a single line.

For a target in a text, you would add something to look for standalone words. I will leave that as an excise to the OP.